# Running the same program with 40 different 'identities' Vs. running 40 instances of the program. Pros and Cons?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, fork, multiple-instances

We're faced here with a certain program-design decision which needs us to know-

1. If and whether there're performance-wise differences between

   a. running multiple(say, n=40) instances of a program(say, n=40); and,

   b. Changing the source-code of the program only enough to change the name of it (say, the program is named XXXXX, and we change the source code and recompile and install XXXX1, XXXX2,XXXX3.... up to XXXX40) and run all of them at once.
2. If yes, what those differences are?

Comment: Huh? (And what does this have to do with `fork()`?)

Comment: Because, those who fork a program and run the forked one alongside the original might know. (That's what I thought. You're free to differ. Giving a reason for the difference might help me learn a few things. Thanks in advance. :) Cheers!)

Comment: Hardcoding anything that's meant to change between runs is reason enough to disqualify B.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that if you run the exact same binary multiple times, the operating system will only need to load one copy into memory and every running instance will share the read-only parts (code, resources, etc). Even writable parts will shared until they are actually written to thanks to [Copy on Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Copy-on-write_in_virtual_memory_management).

If you make a bunch of different binaries, each file will have to be loaded into memory separately. This will increase memory usage and process startup time.

Whether these effects are significant enough to worry about will depend on the specifics of your situation.

Comment: The thing is, we need to use DBus protocol to manage the said program. And as far as I know, if you're using Dbus, you can have just one instance of the program. Does changing the name of the program the way you've shown to, would serve my purpose(so I don't really have to tinker with the source-code)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only you know what you mean by "performance", so do your own benchmarking.

You shouldn't need to change the source code of a program to change its name. Just:

```
 $ cp myprogram myprogram2
```

Or, make every item the same file:

```
 $ ln myprogram2 myprogram
```

I would anticipate Linux doing something smart if you ran `myprogram` and `myprogram2` where both are links to the same file. However, for as few as 40 simultaneous instances, I'd be surprised if the effect was measurable.

I see no advantage in having different names, however. Running multiple instances of the same executable file is a common thing to do.

Comment: The thing is, we need to use DBus protocol to manage the said program. And as far as I know, if you're using Dbus, you can have just one instance of the program. Does changing the name of the program the way you've shown to, would serve my purpose(so I don't really have to tinker with the source-code)? Thanks in advance.